# Google Analytics Goals - How to know if user is using multiple browser tabs/windows?

Tags: google-analytics, registration

I've set up a goal for the signup process on my site, and I can see that users exit the Goal funnel at a page with nothing but a input and a next button, landing on another page  on my site.

I'm guessing this is when users create fake profiles in one tab, while having another tab open somewhere else.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to deal with this? I'm not even sure what's best practice here, here's a few ideas:

1. Force the user to finish these steps as long as he is signed in for the first time and havent completed them, but that would be a development issue.
2. Setting cookies in the signup steps, and (if first time signed in) add a check globally on the site that redirects the user to the last step.
3. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Even if a user has multiple tabs open to GA the requests are serialized and they all look like one browsing session. I do not believe you can check for this with GA at all.